# How to transplant branch from one repository to a new one without history?

Tags: git

I have an existing repository that has reached a certain storage cap.

However, now I want to transplant several branches from the old to a new repository, without the baggage of old history (since the git history is the culprit of that storage issue)

Is there any git command or sequence of commands that could help me do that?

e.g

```
cd old_repo/
git checkout old_repo_old_branch

git remote add origin new_repo
git push origin new_repo_new_branch ?? // Does this preserve the history
```

Edit: Thanks in advance, pardon me for my rudeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> git push origin new_repo_new_branch ?? // Does this preserve the history

Yes, `new_repo_new_branch` preserves the history.

You can *checkout* a new branch with `--orphan` flag. This will erase all previous commit histories.

```
$ cd old_repo/
$ git checkout old_repo_old_branch

$ git checkout --orphan new-branch       # checkout a new branch (say, new-branch) cleaning all previous commit histories
$ git log                                # see commit history is empty

$ git remote add newrepo <new-repo-url>  # add a new remote (say, newrepo) with new-repo-url
$ git push -u newrepo HEAD               # push to newrepo/new-branch
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with good old `cp` rather easy:

```
# create a new repo
git init new_repo

# fetch the content from the old repo
cd old_repo
git archive --format=tar master > ../new_repo/data.tar

# unpack the old content and...
cd ../new_repo
tar xf data.tar

# add it to the new repo
git add .
git commit -m 'clean slate'
```

Repeating for other branches, start in `new_repo`:

```
git checkout --orphan branch-foo
cd ../old-repo
git archive --format=tar branch-foo > ../new_repo/data.tar
# rinse and repeat like above
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends exactly what you have in mind when you talk about leaving the history baggage behind, but I think the simplest solution might be a shallow clone.

If you want, say, the most recent 5 commits on every branch, you could do

```
git clone --depth=5 --no-single-branch url-for-old-repo
```

(Note that the `depth` option will not work if you just give a local file path; you have to use a URL starting with `file:` instead if the origin is local.)

This has some advantages over the approaches others have suggested.  Your new repo contains *the same commits* (with their original SHA1 id) that were in the original repo, and your continued development therefore has a traceable connection to the old history even though it's not in the new repo. (Of course, to *actually* track to the older history you have to look at the old repo, but at least it can be done.)

If you need to pick and choose branches, or set different depth for different branches, or make sure that the depth is enough to capture branch points.... this all can be done, albeit with more work.